# How to change the config file for MathJax in doxygen?

Tags: doxygen, mathjax

I am using doxygen 1.8.9.1 and want to use AsciiMath in the hmtl output. It requires me to use a new config file, i.e. http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=AM_HTMLorMML. However, the configuration "MATHJAX_RELPATH" can only set the root path of mathjax.

How could I change the config to mathjax? Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT:

I have tried to use `MATHJAX_CODEFILE` to change the config file "config: ["local/local.js","MMLtoHTML.js"]", but don't work for me. The URL should be modified, not just the configuration files. (i.e. `MathJax.js?config=AM_HTMLorMML`).

BTW: The render html should be change from `\[sum_(i=1)^n i^3=((n*(n+1))/2)^2\]` to `` `sum_(i=1)^n i^3=((n*(n+1))/2)^2` ``.

Comment: Can you load / enable the config by means of the MATHJAX_CODEFILE possibility, i.e. place here the code to start the AM_HTMLorMML

Comment: @albert Thanks for your suggestions. I have tried to change MATHJAX_CODEFILE, but don't work for me. Will edit my question to show my changes.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to modify **MATHJAX** section of **footer.html** in the Doxygen folder.

For example, use this to modify the url to **MathJax.js?config=local/local.js**

```
<!-- BEGIN MATHJAX-->
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js", "TeX/AMSmath.js", "TeX/AMSsymbols.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
});
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="../mathjax/MathJax.js?config=local/local.js"></script>
<!-- END MATHJAX-->
```

The **$mathjax** line of **header.html** should also be deleted.